# Kivy: bottom navigation bar

Tags: python, kivy, bottomnavigationview

It seems that kivy does not provide a bottom navigation bar (like *BottomNavigationView* on Android).

As I'm quite new to Kivy I wanted to ask what would be the best approach to implement such functionality?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Action Bar](https://kivy.org/doc/stable/api-kivy.uix.actionbar.html) can be placed at the bottom of the screen too.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.lang import Builder

Builder.load_string('''
<MyWidget>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            use_separator: True
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
    Label:
        text: 'content'
    ActionBar:
        ActionView:
            ActionPrevious:
                title: 'Action Bar'
                with_previous: False
''')


class MyWidget(BoxLayout):
    pass


class TestApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return MyWidget()


TestApp().run()
```